# Unable to get unstripped runtime libs from buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I am trying to get buildroot 2012.08 to generate unstripped libs and binaries in output/staging. I enabled "Build packages with debugging symbols" under Build options:

```
BR2_ENABLE_DEBUG=y
# BR2_DEBUG_1 is not set
BR2_DEBUG_2=y
# BR2_DEBUG_3 is not set
# BR2_STRIP_strip is not set
BR2_STRIP_sstrip=y
```

This is what I get:

```
$ file output/staging/lib/*
output/staging/lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so:    ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0:           symbolic link to `ld-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libcrypt-0.9.33.2.so:     ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libcrypt.so.0:            symbolic link to `libcrypt-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libc.so.0:                symbolic link to `libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libdl-0.9.33.2.so:        ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libdl.so.0:               symbolic link to `libdl-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libgcc_s.so:              symbolic link to `libgcc_s.so.1'
output/staging/lib/libgcc_s.so.1:            ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, not stripped
output/staging/lib/libiw.so:                 symbolic link to `libiw.so.29'
output/staging/lib/libiw.so.29:              ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, not stripped
output/staging/lib/libm-0.9.33.2.so:         ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libm.so.0:                symbolic link to `libm-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libnsl-0.9.33.2.so:       ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libnsl.so.0:              symbolic link to `libnsl-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libpthread-0.9.33.2.so:   ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, not stripped
output/staging/lib/libpthread.so.0:          symbolic link to `libpthread-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libresolv-0.9.33.2.so:    ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libresolv.so.0:           symbolic link to `libresolv-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/librt-0.9.33.2.so:        ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/librt.so.0:               symbolic link to `librt-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libthread_db-0.9.33.2.so: ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, not stripped
output/staging/lib/libthread_db.so.1:        symbolic link to `libthread_db-0.9.33.2.so'
output/staging/lib/libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so:    ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libutil-0.9.33.2.so:      ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70403, stripped
output/staging/lib/libutil.so.0:             symbolic link to `libutil-0.9.33.2.so'
```

All stripped except libpthread and libthread_db !!

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

2012.05 has the same problem. 2013.11 fixes it: all libs came unstripped.

Answer (score 2):

Stripping and debug symbols are independent items - though stripping in buildroot does also remove the debug symbols.

To disable stripping, you need to set BR2_STRIP_none: choose *none* in *strip command for binaries on target*. Don't forget to make clean after selecting this option. You can also add a list of files or directories that should not be stripped, in the *executables that should not be stripped* option.

The strip options, however, only affect the binaries and libraries on the target. Buildroot never strips the binaries and libraries in output/staging. However, the individual package build systems may do that. In the question, you refer to the standard C libraries generated by uClibc. uClibc's configuration has a specific option for stripping: DOSTRIP - and this option defaults to true. Buildroot tries to set that option according to the BR2_STRIP choice, but this didn't work correctly before commit e090aeaa from mid-December 2013.

Comment: The BR2_STRIP_XXX is for stripping the binaries and run-time libs on the target rootfs. The BR2_ENABLE_DEBUG in the question is supposed to provide those target libs unstripped under output/staging (to be used with gdb/gdbserver). Clearly BR2_STRIP_XXX should not affect what's under staging. However,out of despair, I tried BR2_STRIP_none and it had no effect: still libs under staging where stripped (as above, which is good for my sanity).

Comment: @srd: Sorry, I didn't read the question in sufficient detail - I thought you were talking about target. The strip option for uClibc is separate - I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure of the date ? 2013.11 released in 30 Nov fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with 2012.02, and there is a simple cure for this. Just edit your uclibc config file (in my case it was toolchain/uClibc/uClibc-0.9.32.config) and change line

```
DOSTRIP=y
```

to

```
# DOSTRIP is not set
```

This will disable stripping uclibc libraries during build time:

```
$ file output/staging/lib/*
output/staging/lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.32.1.so:    ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
output/staging/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0:           symbolic link to `ld-uClibc-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libcrypt-0.9.32.1.so:     ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libcrypt.so.0:            symbolic link to `libcrypt-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libc.so.0:                symbolic link to `libuClibc-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libdl-0.9.32.1.so:        ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libdl.so.0:               symbolic link to `libdl-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libgcc_s.so:              ASCII text
output/staging/lib/libgcc_s.so.1:            ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
output/staging/lib/libm-0.9.32.1.so:         ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libm.so.0:                symbolic link to `libm-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libnsl-0.9.32.1.so:       ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libnsl.so.0:              symbolic link to `libnsl-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libpthread-0.9.32.1.so:   ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libpthread.so.0:          symbolic link to `libpthread-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libresolv-0.9.32.1.so:    ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libresolv.so.0:           symbolic link to `libresolv-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/librt-0.9.32.1.so:        ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/librt.so.0:               symbolic link to `librt-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libthread_db-0.9.32.1.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libthread_db.so.1:        symbolic link to `libthread_db-0.9.32.1.so' 
output/staging/lib/libuClibc-0.9.32.1.so:    ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libutil-0.9.32.1.so:      ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
output/staging/lib/libutil.so.0:             symbolic link to `libutil-0.9.32.1.so'
```

All unstripped.